# How to remove an object from a nested array by match ObjectId field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My web app has teams and users. When a user is added to a team, a new member object created in the team members array. The user ObjectId is kept under the member object. Now, I need to handle a case where the user is deleted, meaning the member should be removed from all teams the user is found under their member's array.  I use mongoose and nodeJs

note: I can't match by objectId field

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Show your schema

Comment: That's the message likely to be attached to your question when it is closed, which it certainly will be unless you take the advice now. Your "question" reads like an opening paragraph for a chat room. This is not that, so please "ask a question" by actually showing a "reproducible example" just as outlined in the link given

Answer (score 3):

I am trying to answer based on your description. If you find any problem then please upload specific code and your schema structure.

```
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId; 

Team.update(
  { },
  { $pull: { members: { _id: new ObjectId(id) } } }, // Here , id is variable where your userid is stored
  { multi: true }
)
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: no need multi true because objectID always unique , and in mongoose no need seperate convertion to Object id , we can directly pass string

Comment: Lalit tnx for your response ! it doesn't seems to work although you understood me correctly. maybeI need to save team at the end ? or use match ?

Comment: Ratan, the teams the user obj/document is associated with can be many

Comment: Lalit, I need the query part as well. I struggle to find the right syntax

Comment: const TeamSchema = new Schema({
  members: [{
    _id: false,
    member: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},
    role: {
    _id: false,
    roleName: {type: String, default: 'Employee', required: true}
    }
}, {usePushEach: true});

Comment: Can you provide sample records for Team ? So , I can help you in building query.